# Datastax Spark Zeppelin Authentication

Tags: apache-spark, connection, datastax, apache-zeppelin

I have a datastax cluster 4.8 (Cassandra + Spark) with authentication activated. I would like to be able to use the [notebook Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/) on my cluster with the Spark master and my database Cassandra.

I donwload the Binary package 0.5.6 of Zeppelin. I put it on my server. If I start it (./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start) with default conf it's work fine http://ServerName:8080/#/.

But when I want to use my DSE spark master, the result output is:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:344)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.init(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:104)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:198)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:169) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:322)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It's seems like the notebook can't connect to the spark-master that I usually call with

> $> dse -u "username" -p "password" spark

I'm not sure that's the problem but I can't figure out where to set those parameters xD.

For information, I set /zeppelin-0.5.6-incubating-bin-all/conf/zeppelin-env.sh with :

- `export MASTER=spark://ip_of_my_server:7077`
- `export ZEPPELIN_MEM=-Xmx5g` as it's suggest in the pull request [ZEPPELIN-305](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-305) mentioned in [Hello world in zeppelin failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735645/hello-world-in-zeppelin-failed) (but i don't think it's the problem, since this request is closed in 0.5.6)
- `export SPARK_HOME=/usr/share/dse/spark` containing :

> bin
>   data
>   lib
>   python
>   RELEASE
>   sbin
>   spark-jobserver

I although put "spark://ip_of_my_server:7077 " in "master" field on the interpreter interface.

So have you any idea for solve my problem and connect DSE spark and zeppelin :)?

Comment: I find in the zeppelin-root-labgsd2t.out :
`Failed to find Spark assembly in /usr/share/dse/spark/lib.
You need to build Spark before running this program.`

So do you know where is the Spark assembly of DSE ?

Answer (score 2):

After some echanges with the Datastax expert [Duy Hai Doan](https://fr.linkedin.com/in/duyhai-doan-8482242)

I get a solution, I advise you to go on his blog http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2325

And for the authentification details, go to interpreter parameter and add :

- **For Cassandra**

> cassandra.hosts : "YourNodeIP"
>
> cassandra.credentials.username : "YourUserName"
>
> cassandra.credentials.password : "YourPassword"

---

- **For Spark**

> spark.cassandra.auth.password : "YourPassword"
>
> spark.cassandra.auth.username : "YourUserName"
>
> spark.cassandra.connection.host : "YourSparkMasterIP"

Big thank to Datastax and Duy