# Zeppelin on WSL. java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process

Tags: java, python, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I am new to Zeppelin and want to install it on my Windows10Pro/WSL machine.
These installation scripts are used https://github.com/x4ax/lxss-install-zeppelin .

Since it is three years old, I had to modify it a bit, so I have:

- Ubuntu 20.04, bash
- zeppelin-0.9.0-bin-all
- hadoop-3.3.0
- spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
- I link python3 to python

Everything is installed, hadoop and spark are successfully tested with provided scripts. At the end I managed to see "**Welcome to Zeppelin!**" landing page.

First, I go to the provided tutorial python notes, "**1.IPython Basic**" and run first cell with %md only. I get the error message":
"

> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
> null
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:271)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:444)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:72)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:182)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
> null
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:126)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:68)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:104)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:154)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:126)
> ... 13 more

Info from md-shared.log

> INFO [2021-01-14 18:54:46,610] ({RemoteInterpreterServer-Thread} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[run]:193) - Launching ThriftServer at 169.254.120.3:52579
> INFO [2021-01-14 18:54:47,785] ({RegisterThread} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[run]:609) - Registering interpreter process
> ERROR [2021-01-14 18:54:47,790] ({RegisterThread} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[run]:613) - Error while registering interpreter: RegisterInfo(host:169.254.120.3, port:52579, interpreterGroupId:md-shared_process), cause: {}
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.zeppelin.shaded.org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)

Which means that there is some network problem

Steps to find solution:

1. From logs I see the command like this, which is run by RemoteInterpreter java-object:

> /usr/local/zeppelin/bin/interpreter.sh -d /usr/local/zeppelin/interpreter/md -c 169.254.120.3 -p 52579 -r : -i md-shared_process -l /usr/local/zeppelin/local-repo/md -g md

It runs silently.

2. zeppelin-daemon.sh start/stop run ok. 'status' also shows correct status. So, restart does not help.
3. Reinstall of zeppelin and of wsl did not help.
4. I also tested problem while firewall was shutdown.

I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

By looking here [Hello world in zeppelin failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735645/hello-world-in-zeppelin-failed) I managed to run md interpreter by fixing in **conf/zeppelin-env.sh**

```
ZEPPELIN_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
```

I saw some statements (*I cannot confirm them*!) that:

- Microsoft WSL blocks random addressing or
- WSL listens to localhost only if it is really local.

PS. Now, I have difficulty to run python interpreter, but that is another problem.
(Besides, it can be linked to my aliasing of python with python3 or similar shell settings).